# While Loop/If statement trouble

Tags: linux, shell-script

second-time poster, still a rookie. 
I'm tasked with an assignment for writing a short program offering the user a cup of tea. The idea is to demonstrate efficient usage of **while loops and if statements**.

The user is asked "Would you like a cup of tea?". If the user responds Yes, the script ends.

If the user says No [N], the script proceeds to ask "Are you sure?" **four more times**. If at any point in these 4 repetitions the user says Yes [Y], the script will end.

Here is my script so far. I executed it and got it working as far as saying Yes goes, but the loopable "No" is causing me trouble; and I can't seem to get it to execute at all now - I'm getting the following message

```
`syntax error: near unexpected token 'else'`
```

Here is my script in full. Again, I'm very new to this, so any and all feedback is heartily welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $refusals != 4 ]]
do
    echo "Will you have a cup of tea? [Y/N]"
    read response
    $refusals = 0

    if [[ $response = Y ]] || [[ $response = y ]]
    then
        $refusals = 4
        echo "Great, I'll make tea now!"
        exit
    elif [[ $response = N ]] || [[ $response = n ]]
        $refusals = [[ $refusals+1 ]]
        echo "Are you sure?"
        read response

    else
        echo "Fine, be that way."
        exit

fi

done
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a `then` after the `elif` condition - however there are many other errors, especially in the variable assignments (which need to look like `refusals=4` not `$refusals = 4`). Check out [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Thanks very much - that's a really great resource! I'll keep plugging away at this.